# Angular watch directive only loads after refresh page

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to make a read more directive.

Currently my directive on works once I refresh the page. I feel like I'm missing a concept here, do I need to initialize the directive into the controller? Is my watch wrong? Currently there is nothing in the controller related to this problem.

HTML:

```
<div data-ng-switch-when="false">
    <div data-ng-bind-html="::sanitizeWidgetContent(widget.content)"
         data-expand-height
         data-ng-class="{true: 'widget-text-collapsed'}[elementHeight>500]"
         class="widget-content">
    </div>

    <div class="fadeout-bottom" data-ng-show="elementHeight>500">
        <button class="btn btn-default btn-fadeout" data-ng-click="elementHeight=false">Read More</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
angular.module('myApp.directives')
    .directive('expandHeight', function () {
        return function (scope, el, attrs) {
            scope.$watch(attrs.expandHeight, function(){
                scope.elementHeight = el[0].offsetHeight;
            });
        }

    });
```

Comment: try exactly like this example [directive](https://www.sitepoint.com/practical-guide-angularjs-directives/), you have to use link, or compile, and one more thing, remove "data-" from you directive name.

Comment: one more thing again! ... use "scopes" instead "attrs"